# Change color based on background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the color based on the background color to make the text more readable.

During my search I found this:

```
var rgb = $('.external-event').css('background-color');
var c = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
var o = Math.round(((parseInt(rgb[0]) * 299) + (parseInt(rgb[1]) * 587) + (parseInt(rgb[2]) * 114)) / 1000);

//console.log(o);
if (o > 125) {
  $('.external-event').css('color', 'black');
} else {
  $('.external-event').css('color', 'white');
}

$('.external-event').css('background-color', c);

var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
var g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

rgb[0] = r;
rgb[1] = g;
rgb[2] = b;
```

The problem is that it's only displaying white color and not changing to black.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txnr70jL/).

for some reason this example is doing the opposite then my actual development environment and keeping the text in black even with a black background.

EDIT: I forgot to add I am dynamically displaying multiple background colors with the same class `.external-event` and it seems to be only getting the rgb value of the first element.

Comment: You've declared `rgb` as the background color of the first element in a JQuery wrapped set that contains all the elements that match the `.external-event` selector. Then you are treating `rgb` like an array and assigning your generated color values into it with `rgb[0]`, `rgb[1]` and `rgb[2]`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Actually `css` with a single parameter returns a string representing the value of that style property for the element.  He's still using it incorrectly though...

Comment: @WillP. That's exactly what my comment says.

Comment: using jquery you'll get "r" from rgb[0] because it'll return a string, i think you are looking for something else https://jsfiddle.net/txnr70jL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Sam Onela's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252953/1575353) I was able to figure it out.

Here is what I did:

```
$('.external-event').each(function() {

    var rgb = $(this).css('background-color');
    var pattern = /rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/;
    var matches = rgb.match(pattern);

    var o = Math.round(((parseInt(matches[1]) * 299) + (parseInt(matches[2]) * 587) + (parseInt(matches[3]) * 114)) /1000);

    //console.log(o);
    if(o > 125) {
        $(this).css('color', '#444444');
    }else{
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The issue:

[.css('background-color')](http://api.jquery.com/css/) returns a *string literal* representing the background color in [Functional format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()) - i.e. *rgb(R,G,B)*, where *R* is the red value, *G* is the green value, and *B* is the blue value.

The first character (i.e. `rgb[0]`) would be `r`, the second character would be `g`, etc...Additionally, passing a character to [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (i.e. `parseInt(rgb[0])`) yields [*`NaN`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). Consequently, `NaN > 0` will always evaluate to *false*. So that is why your code example always sets the (text foreground) color to *white*.

#### Solutions:

In order to get the individual values for the red, green and blue numbers, one option is to remove the `rgb()` using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and split the values into an array using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like this:

```
var rgbValues = rgb.replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(', ');
//rgbValues:  ["0", "0", "0"]
```

Another option is to use a regular expression to match it, using [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) like in the example below.

```
var rgb = $('.external-event').css('background-color');
var pattern = /rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/;
//matches will be an array containing the elements:
//0- the group matched i.e. rgb(0, 0, 0)
//1- the r value
//2- the g value
//3- the b value
var matches = rgb.match(pattern);
```

**Note:** Also see the section down below about [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

See a demonstration by expanding the snippet below.

```js
var rgb = $('.external-event').css('background-color');
//remove the rgb() characters and split into an array
var rgbValues = rgb.replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(', ');
//or use a regular expression
var pattern = /rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/;
var matches = rgb.match(pattern);
if (matches.length && matches.length > 3) {
  var c = 'rgb(' + matches[1] + ',' + matches[2] + ',' + matches[3] + ')';
  var o = Math.round(((parseInt(matches[1], 10) * 299) + (parseInt(matches[2], 10) * 587) + (parseInt(matches[3], 10) * 114)) / 1000);

  console.log('rgb: ', rgb, ' c: ', c, ' o : ', o, ' matches: [' + matches.join(", ")+']', ' rgbValues: [' + rgbValues.join(", ")+']');
  if (o > 125) {
    $('.external-event').css('color', 'black');
  } else {
    $('.external-event').css('color', 'white');
  }

  $('.external-event').css('background-color', c);
}
```

```css
.external-event {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="external-event">
  <br />external event
  <br />
</div>
```

#### Edit

The question [has been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41252775/4) to state "*I forgot to add I am dynamically displaying multiple background colors with the same class *.external-event* and it seems to be only getting the rgb value of the first element.*"

Use the jQyery method [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the elements containing the class *.external-event*. The callback can accept two [parameters](http://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function): the index as well as the [element](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element) (same as `this` in the context of the callback).

```
var externalEvents = $('.external-event');
    externalEvents.each(function(index, externalEvent) {
        //check background color of externalEvent - 
        //$(this) == $(externalEvent)
```

See this demonstrated by expanding the code snippet below.

```js
$(function() { //jQuery DOM-loaded callback
  var externalEvents = $('.external-event');
  externalEvents.each(function(index, externalEvent) {
    var rgb = $(externalEvent).css('background-color');
    //remove the rgb() characters and split into an array
    var rgbValues = rgb.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')', '').split(', ');
    //or use a regular expression
    var pattern = /rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/;
    var matches = rgb.match(pattern);
    if (matches.length && matches.length > 3) {
      var c = 'rgb(' + matches[1] + ',' + matches[2] + ',' + matches[3] + ')';
      var o = Math.round(((parseInt(matches[1], 10) * 299) + (parseInt(matches[2], 10) * 587) + (parseInt(matches[3], 10) * 114)) / 1000);

      console.log('rgb: ', rgb, ' c: ', c, ' o : ', o, ' matches: [' + matches.join(", ")+']', ' rgbValues: [' + rgbValues.join(", ")+']');
      if (o > 125) {
        $(externalEvent).css('color', 'black');
      } else {
        $(externalEvent).css('color', 'white');
      }
      //This isn't needed
     // $(externalEvent).css('background-color', c);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.external-event {
  background-color: #000;
}

.external-event.orange {
  background-color: #fa0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="external-event">
  <br />external event
  <br />
</div>
<div class="external-event orange">
  <br />external event orange
  <br />
</div>
```

### Note about using `parseInt()`

It is a good practice to pass the radix (typically of *10*) to [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), given the following:

> If *radix* is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", *radix* is 16 (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
> - If the input string begins with "0", *radix* is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  **For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt**.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)</sup>

So pass *10* as the radix, like below:

```
parseInt(matches[1], 10)
```